# Is the last digit of $2^{2^{n-1}(2^n-1)}-1$ always $5$ for $n >3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, conjectures, perfect-numbers

Is the last digit of $2^{2^{n-1}(2^n-1)}-1$ always $5$ for $n >3$?

I did modification to the Mersenne numbers (Even perfect numbers) foruma I put that formual to be the power of 2 have got  : $2^{2^{n-1}(2^n-1)}-1$ , Now for some values of $n >3$ that i have tried i have got the produced integer with last digit equal $5$ like [this example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E%282%5E%28n-1%29%282%5En-1%29%29-1%29+%2C+n%3D4), Now to do more $n$ or so large to conjecture that it is beyond of current tecknology , Really am interesting to prove that if it is true ?

Comment: $2^{4k}-1$ has last digit $5$, of course.

Comment: are all of mersenne numbers =0 mod 4 ? I think no

Comment: What @DietrichBurde said can be seen by induction as $$2^{4k+4}-2^{4k}= 15\cdot 2^{4k}\equiv 15\cdot 6 = 80\equiv0 \pmod{10}$$

Comment: I did not say that the Mersenne numbers are congruent $0$ modulo $4$. But the **exponent** is $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)=4k$ for all $n>3$.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik The existence of Mersenne primes proves that there are mersenne primes which are not equal to $0$ modulo $4$

Answer (score 1):

Since $N=2^{2^{n-1}(2^n-1)}-1$ is odd, it is enough to show $5\mid N$, and the conclusion follows. But since $2^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, we have $2^{2^{n-1}(2^n-1)}-1=(2^4)^{2^{n-3}(2^n-1)}-1\equiv 1-1=0\pmod {5}$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

We start from.the sequence:
$$2\;\;4\;\;8\;\;16\;\;32\;\;64\;\;128\;\;256\;\;512\;\;1024\;\;2048\;\;4096$$
In particular, we are interested in the power of $2$ such that their last digit is $6$. This occours when $e\equiv0\mod 4$, in fact:
$$2^e\equiv 6 \mod 10 \leftrightarrow e=4n, n\in N$$
Now, to show that $2^{2^{n-1}(2^n-1)}-1\equiv 5 \mod 10$, we need to show that:
$$2^{n-1}(2^n-1)\equiv 0\mod 4$$
Let $n=3+k, k\in N_0$, we have:
$$2^{3+k-1}(2^{3+k}-1)=2^2\cdot2^k\cdot(2^{3+k}-1)=4\cdot(2^{3+k}-1)$$
We are in the form $4a \mod 4$, where $a=(2^{n}-1)$, so:
$$2^{n-1}(2^n-1)\equiv 0\mod 4, \forall n\in N, n>3$$

Note that this proprety holds also for $n=3$ because in that case, we can pick up a $2^2=4$ and so all the expression is congruent to $0$ modulo $4$.

Comment: @zeraoulia rafik: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $1$ or a favourite answer?